# Qt DBus unmarshalling when sent as QDBusVariant / QVariant

Tags: c++, qt5, dbus

Class `Dummy`, derived from `QObject`, registered

```
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(Dummy)
qRegisterMetaType<Dummy>("Dummy");
qDBusRegisterMetaType<Dummy>();
```

When I send `Dummy` as `QDBusVariant`, the slot is correctly called, but the value (of `Dummy`) is default. Have noticed that the unmarshalling operator is never called (marshalling is). Via `DBusMonitor` I can see the value is sent correclty.

I assume it fails because the operator `QDBusArgument &operator<<(const QDBusVariant &arg);` is called and works only against Qt standard types. If I wrap a `QString` in `QVariant` in `QDBusVariant` it works fine.

How can solve the issue?

```
/*!
 * \brief operator << Marshalling
 * \param argument
 * \param dummy
 * \return
 */
QDBusArgument &operator<<(QDBusArgument &argument, const Dummy& dummy)
{
    argument.beginStructure();
    argument << dummy.m_number; // qint32
    argument << dummy.m_string; // QString
    argument.endStructure();
    qDebug() << "Marshall to DBus" << dummy.m_number << dummy.m_string;
    return argument;
}

/*!
 * \brief operator >> unmarshalling
 * \param argument
 * \param dummy
 * \return
 */
const QDBusArgument &operator>>(const QDBusArgument &argument, Dummy &dummy)
{
    argument.beginStructure();
    argument >> dummy.m_number;
    argument >> dummy.m_string;
    argument.endStructure();
    qDebug() << "Unmarshall from DBus" << dummy.m_number << dummy.m_string;
    return argument;
}
```

Sending:

```
        Dummy dummy(c++, "Moep");
        qDebug() << "Dummy is" << dummy;
        QVariant qv;
        qv.setValue(dummy);
        QDBusVariant qdv = QDBusVariant(qv);
        testserviceInterface.receiveVariant(qdv);
```

Remarks:

1. Qt 5.1 Win32
2. This here describes a similar issue with no answer as of posting date: [Qt QDbus Sending Custom Types with QVariant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14086545/qt-qdbus-sending-custom-types-with-qvariant)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is, that the received `QVariant` for complex types is of type `QDBusArgument`. If it is possible to unmarshall to the desired target type, then the way to do it, is: `qv.value<QDBusArgument>() >> someConcreteObject`